# Timeout for a HTTP Resquest

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

Is there another ProgID instead of **"MSXML2.XMLHTTP"** that lets you set a timeout in **VBScript**?
***OnReadyStateChange*** or similar must also work in VBScript.

```
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.timeout = 10000 'Throws an error
oHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", True

oHTTP.OnReadyStateChange = GetRef("oHTTP_OnReadyStateChange")

Sub oHTTP_OnReadyStateChange
    ' do something
End sub

oHTTP.Send
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [ServerXmlHttp with setTimeouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Y897), or just use [windows.XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.